# Calculate between two dates to percent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to calculate between two dates difference to percent. Only not date, hours needed to scale.
Example:

```
22-08-2017 09:00 start date,
30.09.2017 22:00 finish date,
```

The today date is `01.09.2017`. When I look to system today, the application show to me "%47 percent completed" I want to this.

Comment: Please show us some code, you do the work, we will help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getpercent(){
var strt = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value).getTime();

var end = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value).getTime();

var current = new Date(document.getElementById('current').value).getTime();

var completed = ((current - strt) / (end - strt)) * 100;
document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = completed+"%";
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>start <input id="start" type="date" /></p>
<p>end <input id="end" type="date" /></p>
<p>current <input id="current" type="date" /></p>
<p>percent   <span id="percent"></span></p>
<button onclick="getpercent()">get percent</button>
```

new Date() will take a date string and turn it into unix standard time as seconds.

Comment: you can use the tidy button in snippet to align the code

Comment: What do you need jQuery for?

Comment: check this i added input

Comment: Can the clock be added?

Comment: you want the hour's !?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript Date object can be used in arithmetic expressions. It will convert to milliseconds.

```
var start, finish, midpoint, percent, elapsed;

start = new Date(2017, 8, 22, 9);
finish = new Date(2017, 9, 30, 22);
midpoint = new Date(2017, 8, 29, 12);

elapsed = midpoint - start;
percent = (elapsed / (finish - start)) * 100;

console.log('elapsed', elapsed, ' ms', percent, ' % complete');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwb3g4nc/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple class `DiffTracker` that accepts two dates in the constructor - `start` and `end` date and has one method `getPercentage()` that will return the percentage of hours passed from start date against the total hours between `start` and `end` date.

Let's see the following scenario:

Start Date = 2017-08-23 09:00

End Date = 2017-08-24 09:00

So now the total difference of hours is **24**

If we call `getPercentage()` with date 2017-08-24 21:00 we should see result of **50%**. 
If we call `getPercentage()` with date 2017-08-24 03:00 we should see result of **75%** because the difference is 18 hours

```js
var diffTraker = new DiffTracker(new Date(2017, 7, 23, 9), new Date(2017, 7, 24, 9));

console.log('Start Date');
console.log(new Date(2017, 7, 23, 9));
console.log('-------------------');
console.log('End Date');
console.log(new Date(2017, 7, 24, 9));
console.log('-------------------');
console.log(diffTraker.getPercentage(new Date(2017, 7, 23, 21)) + '% from start date (' + new Date(2017, 7, 23, 21) + ')');
console.log(diffTraker.getPercentage(new Date(2017, 7, 24, 3)) + '% from start date (' + new Date(2017, 7, 24, 3) + ')');
console.log(diffTraker.getPercentage(new Date(2017, 7, 24, 5)) + '% from start date (' + new Date(2017, 7, 24, 5) + ')');

function DiffTracker(startDate, endDate){
  var self = this;
  self.start = startDate;
  self.end = endDate;
  self.totalHours =  getDiffHours(self.start, self.end);
  
  self.getPercentage = function(date){
    var hoursFromStart = getDiffHours(self.start, date);
    return (hoursFromStart * 100 / self.totalHours).toFixed(2);
  }
  
  function getDiffHours(start, end){
    /* 36e5 is the scientific notation for 60*60*1000, dividing by which converts the milliseconds difference into hours */
    return Math.abs(start - end) / 36e5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php i use this method:

```
<?php
$FirstDate = "22-08-2017 09:00";
$SecondDate = "30.09.2017 22:00";

$start = strtotime($FirstDate);
$finish = strtotime($SecondDate);

$diff = $finish - $start;

$progress = time() - $start; // You might have to modify the time function depending on where you live
$procent = ($progress / $diff) * 100;

$width = round($procent);

// The if statment below just makes sure that it does not show 110% for example.
if ($width >= 100)
{
    echo "100 %";
}
else
{
    echo $width;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

$FirstDate = "**22**-08-2017 09:00";
$SecondDate = "**23**.09.2017 22:00";

Even if one day it shows 100%